# Twilio send message doesn't work

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I have a lib with service witch calls Twilio api to send sms message. This lib is used in ASP MWC project. And the fuction SendMessage returns null. I pasted this code in a new console app, and it worked well - sms message has been sent. I don't understand why the exact same code doesn't work in my project.

Twilio.Api 3.4.1.0

Code

```
            string AuthToken = "___";

            string AccountSid = "___";

            string Sender = "___";

            TwilioRestClient Client = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

            var smsMessage = Client.SendMessage(Sender, "197_______1", "Some text");
```

Maybe the is a problem with ssl? How to check it?

Comment: You should probably edit that phone number for the purpose of the sample code and put a generic 555 number. Anyways, it sounds like a configuration issue. Is there an API key or something you are missing?

Comment: The number for purpose was just test number, but yeah, i've deleted it. What do you mean, configuration issue, - that i configured TwilioRestClient wrong? But it's all code i have for sending sms messages. What else should i add in configuration? Where should i add API key?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319262/twilio-transactional-messages-to-indian-dnd-numbers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In global.asax file in Application_Start method I commented out code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

And sending messages's worked.
So i suggested that the issue was because of on my machine ssl protocol wasn't set up. But i think that for live server this isn't a good solution. And admins told me that on local machine they set up tls protocole. So I hope that when I write in global asax:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

On live server sending messages will work.
If i found out it in a wrong way, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

First, I'd making sure that the NuGet package you've pulled into your project is the latest version (4.0.2 I beleive).  Note that the package version is different than the actual assembly version.

Second, check to see if the RestException property is null:

```
if (Client.RestException != null) {
    //something bad happened
}
```

Finally, if neither of those suggestions help, break out an HTTP proxy tool like Fiddler and check to see if the library is actually making a successful HTTP request to Twilio.

Hope that helps.